# We can use [Get Files (properties only)] and [Get file properties] to get folders.. is it a bug or it is an intended behavioure?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, power-automate

Inside my workflow i want to get Folder properties and Folders based on filter Query as follow:-

1. Get File Properties:-

[image: johnjohn123_1-1690338210338.png]

2. Get file (Properties only):-

[image]

so is it a bug that those actions return folders beside the files (as their names refer to files not folder)? or it is the intended behavior?  can i keep using them to get folders or i should replace those actions with other actions?

Thanks